# Sample values with different types of

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, .net-4.0

code is worked:

```
var reports = repository.GetAll().ToList().
    Where(r => r.Documents.
                 Where(d => d.Reports.
                              Where(rw => rw.ID == reportID).Any()).Any()).
    ToList<IDocumentObjects>();
```

but I do not want to use ToList
this code call a error:

```
var reports = repository.GetAll().
     Where(r => r.Documents.
                   Where(d => d.Reports.
                                 Where(rw => rw.ID == reportID).Any()).Any()).
     ToList<IDocumentObjects>();
```

error:

> Member access 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[IReport] Reports' of 'IDocument' not legal on type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[IDocument].

**QUESTION:** How create this request with out ToList in GetAll() ?

Comment: repository - IDocumentRepository

Comment: That looks like an extremely expensive way of getting the data. You should join the tables instead.

Comment: sorry, IQuerable<IDocumentObjects> GetAll –

Comment: It is because you are hiding your entities behind the interfaces and not all linq providers supports such way.

Comment: Could you show your .GetAll() implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Your navigation properties use interfaces instead of entity types (the exception mentions `IReport` and `IDocument`). Change it to implementations and try it again. EF doesn't support interfaces.

Comment: I need to use interfaces, both on the other to solve this problem?

Comment: If you need to use interfaces EF is not good technology for you.